# Maximizing volume and value, minimizing weight in a knapsack

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

Trying out a Knapsack variant where the rules are

1. Any item you take must fit completely in the bag
2. Usable metrics of the bag are length(l),width(w),height(h) and you can assume that if the products fit into the bag both individually and together by total volume, there is a way to pack them in
3. Price value must be maximized
4. Weight must be minimized without compromising on dollar value

The input is basically a list of items with l,w,h, value in dollars and weight. Seems like thats a lot of metrics apart from the regular knapsack variants. What I am doing is first eliminating all products that dont fit into the bag (volume and dimensions wise). Next I am doing regular knapsack logic (figuring out if each item belongs in the bag or not) based on volume and price using the common DP pseudo code

```
if (volume[i] > V) {
        return knapsack(i-1, V);
    } else {
        return Math.max(knapsack(i-1, V), knapsack(i-1, V - volume[i]) + values[i]);
    }
```

This seems to go haywire considering maximum l,w,h of the bag is like 40, 40, 40. (Hence volume is 64000) and number of items is to the tune of 16k. (Java out of memory error). Trying out Branch and Bound (not sure if correctly though). Also not sure how to fit the least weight constraint in

Another suboptimal way I've tried is to use heuristics based on value/weight ratio and then taking the best volume fit. Another way would be to find all possible knapsack solutions and then pick out the best weight fit (But again this would be hyper exponential)

How to solve this?